How would you label these chords?

The piece is in Ab major.
In mm.7-8 a cadence appears and there are several non-chord tones with accidentals.
I attempted to label chord symbols on my own, but they are very uncharacteristic of classical music.
Over the course of reading this book(the excerpt is an exercise from the book), I have always expected accidental notes to mean something like modulation and applied chords.
How would you label these cadence chords?

Title and composer?

@Aaron - Looks like the 1st movement of Beethoven's Piano Sonata No. 12 in A Flat Major.


vi  viio7  I  CTo  V

CT = "Common Tone". Common-tone diminished chords like this one serve as a decoration or prolongation of some central chord. In this case, Eb is the common tone bridging I to V through a diminished triad.
For more on common-tone chords, see Understanding function of diminished chord in Paganini's 4th caprice and linked posts.
